# How to add a list to End drawer in flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, navigation-drawer

I am a trying to make an application where i want to display some dates using network call which i have done. Now i want to show that datelist in my endDrawer.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
    Future<List> addDateList(int counter,String date) async {
    DateTime oops = DateTime.now();
    String date = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(oops);
    List<String> dateList = List();

    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://www.example.com/json/' + date + '-17.json');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dateList.add(date);
    } else {
      date = getpreviousdate(date);
      return addDateList(counter,date);
    }
    if (dateList.length == 7) {
      print(dateList);

      return dateList;
    } else {
      date = getpreviousdate(date);
      return addDateList(++counter, (date));
    }
  }

  getpreviousdate(String date) {
    DateTime pastday = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1));
    date = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(pastday);

    return date;
  }
```

Comment: You can just create a `Drawer` with the respective class and add it to the `endDrawer` parameter of the `Scaffold` ... or did you want an example of how this `Drawer` could be done?

Comment: I tried doing this..can you show me one such example?

Comment: I added an answer. Although I have to tell you that the way your code is set up will not work as you would expect. It seems there is a loophole in your `getPreviousDate()`, because you do nothing with the returned value.

Comment: Thank you for the help..I have made changes in the code..I think this will work..pl let me know your view.

Comment: I still didn't get how could i pass my code in your class and achieve the result.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer but when I implemented the answer it is showing only one date (i.e current date)

Comment: I updated it again ... it is a matter of how you call your functions (in which order) and since it is recursive you have to break it at some point to not let it get infinite

Comment: Sure.I will do it.

Comment: i want to display the dates in directly when i swipe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you just want to create a ListView from the collected Date-Strings you can do it like this:

```dart
@immutable
class DrawerView extends StatelessWidget {
  const DrawerView({
    @required this.items,
  }) : assert(items != null);

  final List<String> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: items.map<Widget>((String item) => ListTile(title: Text(item))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I prefer to create a new class for things like this.

---

**EDIT**

OK, you can try this (i did not run it, because i have no such API to test it with, but it should be working just fine):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// [MyApp] class - where it all begins! :D
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  int _counter = 0;
  List<String> _dateList = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addDateList();
  }

  Future addDateList({ DateTime date }) async {
    final DateTime d = date ?? DateTime.now();
    String dateString = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(d);

    http.Response response = await http.get('https://www.example.com/json/$dateString-17.json');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _dateList.add(dateString);
        _counter++;
      });
    }

    // if you reach the desired length or the counter gets too high break the execution
    if (_dateList.length >= 7 || _counter > 50) return true;

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });

    return addDateList(date: d.subtract(Duration(days: 1)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Drawer Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('HOME'),
        ),
        endDrawer: MyDrawer(items: _dateList),
        body: Center(
          child: const Text('DRAWER WITH LISTVIEW - DEMO'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDrawer({
    @required this.items,
  }) : assert(items != null);

  final List<String> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: items.map<Widget>((String item) => ListTile(title: Text(item))).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```